# Leer ficheros en Java usando Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows

tengo un problema para **leer ficheros en Linux** con el siguiente método:

```
/**
     * Traduce palabras desde un fichero que se le especifica por los parametros.
     * @param ruta es la ruta del archivo que se desea traducir
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws PalabraNoEncontradaException
     */
    public void leerFichero(String ruta) throws IOException, PalabraNoEncontradaException{

    FileReader fichero = new FileReader(ruta);

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fichero);

    String linea = buffer.readLine();
    String [] palabrasTexto = new String[5];

    //mientras la lectura de lineas este escrita, lee el archivo
    while (linea != null) {
        palabrasTexto = linea.split(" ");
        linea = buffer.readLine();
    }

    //recorre el array donde se han guardado las palabras del fichero
    for(int recorre=0; recorre<palabrasTexto.length; recorre++) {
        traducir(palabrasTexto[recorre].toLowerCase());
        //System.out.println(palabrasTexto[recorre]);
    }
}
```

El método me funciona en ***Windows***; al hacer llamada al método `traducir(String palabra)`, me traduce el contenido del fichero sin problemas; en cambio, uso el mismo método en ***Linux*** y me da error.
 Al guardar la primera palabra del fichero en el vector `palabrasTexto`, **se guarda con un espacio en la primera posición***(es decir, hola=[' ','h','o','l','a'])*. ¿Alguno puede saber a qué se debe este fallo en Linux y no en Windows?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java tienes en cada sistema?

Comment: @PabloLozano tengo version 1.8 en ambos. No entiendo qué puede fallar.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es debido a la versión que tengas de Java que tengas en Windows y Linux. No es debido al sistema operativo, si no a la version de la JVM, si revisas la documentación de Java en las distintas versiones verás la diferencia en la ejecución del método Split.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043324?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: Ese bug se detectó y solucionó en 2014, en las primeras revisiones de Java 8. Si ésta es la causa, tiene una versión en Windows muy antigua

Comment: Esa es la cuestion, que en Windows dice que le funciona bien, en Linux no

Comment: Me auto-corrijo: no es un bug, se cambió el comportamiento de split() en Java 8, así que el espacio inicial es lo esperado ahora.La JVM en Linux debe ser Java 8 o posterior, la de Windows debe ser Java 7 o anterior

Comment: Pues esperemos que nos responda para saber mas detalles

Comment: Buenas, he visto las versiones que uso de java en Linux y Windows, y ambas son 1.8. He estado comprobando diferentes formas de resolverlo y sigue sin funcionar.